# Use Skobbler map upload app to iTunes Connect happen contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64, i386]'

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, skobbler-maps

I have reference the solution [Stripping Unwanted Architectures From Dynamic Libraries In Xcode](http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/). But after upload to iTunes connect cannot see iOS Builds in Activity.

Who can help me, why would like this, there are other ways to solve it?

Comment: Resolve.  Because I add these keys to info.plist in case I am using Privacy - Camera Usage Description and Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description with a blank description.   Make up the description and then upload it right.

Comment: Hello @Huang Yao Tseng

I'm getting the same error, can you please tell me how you fixed it exactly

ERROR ITMS-90087: "Unsupported Architectures. The executable for Marriott MEA.app/Frameworks/SKMaps.framework contains unsupported architectures '[x86_64, i386]'."

Comment: @pakshaheen You can reference http://ikennd.ac/blog/2015/02/stripping-unwanted-architectures-from-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode/